# How to create AdDuplex control using c#?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, controls

I have AdDuplex control xaml code like below:

```
<adduplex:AdControl Name="adduplexControl" xmlns:adduplex="clr-namespace:AdDuplex;assembly=AdDuplex.AdControl.Silverlight" AppId="myid" Margin="0,68,0,0" Background="Black" />
```

How can I create this control using c#?

I tried like this:

```
AdDuplex.AdControl a = new AdDuplex.AdControl();
a.AppId = "myid";
```

But I don't know how to create `xmlns:adduplex` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That property is an [XML namespace definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).  It is used by the xaml serializer to identify particular types during deserialization.

The namespace follows a specific format, containing the namespace of the type (`AdDuplex`), and the name of the assembly where its definition can be found (**AdDuplex.AdControl.Silverlight.dll**).  The name of the XML namespace is `adduplex` (xmlns:**adduplex**).  With this information, the xaml serializer can locate the `AdControl` type (adduplex:AdControl).

This attribute is added during serialization, and does not affect the state of any instance of `AdControl`.

tl;dr: You don't have to.

Comment: But I want to show AdDuplex control only in trial mode, so in paid version I don't want to show AdDuplex. I've tried delete control after init, however it is visible for moment and maybe it request ad server. So how can I create it using code?

Comment: @lord_t: That's a different question.  Your question was "But I don't know how to create xmlns:adduplex property."  My answer was "**You don't have to.  Move on.**".

Comment: No, my question was "How can I create this control using c#?" :)

Comment: @lord_t: Seems to me that you *did* create it, but you saw that xmlns definition and stopped.  I say unto you, "Do not stop at the xmlns! skip it entirely and move on!"  And, having attempted to try and help you, I must move on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating an `AdDuplex.AdControl` in code:

```
AdDuplex.AdControl adduplex = new AdDuplex.AdControl();
adduplex.AppId = "YOUR_AD_UNIT_HERE";
adduplex.Width = 480;
adduplex.Height = 80;
adduplex.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
adduplex.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
adduplex.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

That's will create a `AdDuplex` banner dynamically.

On `AppId` don't use your app ID, use the adUnit to avoid the "Configuration Error".